# How to connect to Flink SQL Client from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm trying to use Apache Flink's Table concept in one of my projects to combine data from multiple sources in real-time. Unfortunately, all of my team members are Node.JS developers. So, I'm looking for possible ways to connect to Flink from NodeJS and query from it. In [Flink's documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sqlclient/) for SQL Client, it's mentioned that

> The SQL Client aims to provide an easy way of writing, debugging, and submitting table programs to a Flink cluster without a single line of Java or Scala code. The SQL Client CLI allows for retrieving and visualizing real-time results from the running distributed application on the command line.

Based on this, is there any way to connect to Flink's SQL client from NodeJS? Is there any driver already available for this like Node.JS drivers for [MySQL](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) or [MSSQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql). Otherwise, what are the possible ways of achieving this?

Any idea or clarity on achieving this would be greatly helpful and much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently not much that you can do. The SQL Client runs on local machines and connects to the cluster there. I think what will help you is the introduction of the Flink SQL Gateway, which is expected to be released with Flink 1.16. You can read more about that on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-91%3A+Support+SQL+Gateway

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to check out some of the products that offer a FlinkSQL editor on the market, maybe that is useful path for your colleagues.

For example:

https://www.ververica.com/apache-flink-sql-on-ververica-platform
https://docs.cloudera.com/csa/1.7.0/ssb-overview/topics/csa-ssb-intro.html

Note that this is not *exactly* what you asked for, but could be an option to enable your team.